# Compute Custom Swift Class and Supply Results with App

Tags: swift

My app needs a complicated set of UIBezierPaths (stored in a custom class with other properties) which it computes at app startup. This takes over 60 seconds to compute which is too long for regular app load. My solution was to compute it only once and then save in UserDefaults for future app startup loads.

```
class LinePath : UIBezierPath {
    var lineType = LineType.undefined
    var startPoint = CGPoint()
    var endPoint = CGPoint()
    var arcCenter = CGPoint()
    var arcRadius = CGFloat()
    var arcStartAngle = CGFloat()
    var arcEndAngle = CGFloat()
    var arcClockwise = Bool()
    var connects = [LinePath]()
    var lineLayer = LineLayer()
    var group = Int()
    var gradient = CALayer()
}
```

But I want to go one step further and simply compute it in my development and save/supply resultant custom class data with my app. That way every user will not have to compute it but simply read the actual data from the disk which is instantaneous.

I cannot get my head around on how to accomplish this. Simply computing once and spitting it in log and then copy/paste into code seems wrong and I can't figure out the proper way to accomplish this.

Comment: "Simply computing once and spitting it in log and then copy/paste into code seems wrong" Why is it wrong? Isn't that what code generation _is_? Isn't this exactly what you'd do if you were generating drawing code with [PaintCode](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/)? I don't get what the issue is.

Comment: you could just store/write the "resultant custom class data" to a file that you bundle 
with your app, and then just read it when the app starts.

Comment: @workingdog how do i write resultant class in a file?

Comment: you could use `NSKeyedArchiver` to write your custom class as `Data` to a file.
Then add that file to your project, and use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to read it again as your class.
After that, you can store that same `Data` to UserDefaults. I'll see if I can "cook" something up for you, if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example code of using `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to write and read
a class, in this case `UIBezierPath` to and from file. There is a bit of code, but it's not difficult.

On first run (during development), click "write logo to file". The console will print where the file ends up.
Copy and paste that file into your Xcode project directory, right click on your Xcode project and
"Add file to yourproject". Then remove the `writeBezier` button.

On second run click "read logo from file", and the logo should show.

You can also store this same class "Data" to `UserDefaults` as you would normally.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let theFile = "linePathFile"
    @State var bezier = UIBezierPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 55) {
            Button(action: {
                writeBezier(asData(UIBezierPath.logo), to: theFile)
            }) {
                Text("write logo to file")
            }
            Button(action: {
                bezier = loadBezier(from: theFile)
            }) {
                Text("read logo from file")
            }
            // display bezier logo
            ScaledBezier(bezierPath: bezier).stroke(lineWidth: 2).frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        }
    }
    
    func loadBezier(from file: String) -> UIBezierPath {
        do {
            if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: file, withExtension: "bin") {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
                if let bezier = asBezier(data) {
                    return bezier
                }
                return UIBezierPath()
            }
        } catch {
            print("error: \(error)") // todo
        }
        return UIBezierPath()
    }
    
    func writeBezier(_ theData: Data, to file: String) {
        do {
            let fileURL = try FileManager.default
                .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                .appendingPathComponent(file)
                .appendingPathExtension("bin")
            try theData.write(to: fileURL)
            print("----> logo writen to fileURL: \(fileURL)")
        } catch {
            print("could not write file: \(file)")
        }
    }
    
    func asBezier(_ data: Data) -> UIBezierPath? {
        do {
            NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(UIBezierPath.self, forClassName: "UIBezierPath")
            return try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? UIBezierPath
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    func asData(_ bezier: UIBezierPath) -> Data {
        do {
            NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("UIBezierPath", for: UIBezierPath.self)
            return try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: bezier, requiringSecureCoding: false)
        } catch {
            return Data()
        }
    }
    
}

// from: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-uibezierpath-and-cgpath-in-swiftui
extension UIBezierPath {
    /// The Unwrap logo as a Bezier path.
    static var logo: UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.534, y: 0.5816))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.1877, y: 0.088), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.534, y: 0.5816), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.2529, y: 0.4205))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.9728, y: 0.8259), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.4922, y: 0.4949), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 1.0968, y: 0.4148))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0397, y: 0.5431), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.7118, y: 0.5248), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.3329, y: 0.7442))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.6211, y: 0.0279), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.508, y: 1.1956), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 1.3042, y: 0.5345))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.6904, y: 0.3615), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.7282, y: 0.2481), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.6904, y: 0.3615))
        return path
    }
}

// from: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-uibezierpath-and-cgpath-in-swiftui
struct ScaledBezier: Shape {
    let bezierPath: UIBezierPath
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = Path(bezierPath.cgPath)
        
        // Figure out how much bigger we need to make our path in order for it to fill the available space without clipping.
        let multiplier = min(rect.width, rect.height)
        
        // Create an affine transform that uses the multiplier for both dimensions equally.
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: multiplier, y: multiplier)
        
        // Apply that scale and send back the result.
        return path.applying(transform)
    }
}
```

Comment: Coool... I haven't tried it yet but makes perfect sense.

Comment: ```NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData``` is deprecated in iOS12, how to deal with this?

Comment: do a bit of searching on the net and SO, you will come across this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75632048/how-to-replace-nskeyedunarchiver-unarchivetoplevelobjectwithdata-with-unarchived