# How to replace NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData with unarchivedObject when data is a Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedunarchiver

iOS 16.4 deprecates [`unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver/2919664-unarchivetoplevelobjectwithdata) and should be replaced with [`unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver/2983380-unarchivedobject).

When you archived a Swift Dictionary like `[String: Any]`, how do you use the newer API to unarchive it?

`NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: [String: Any].self, from: data)` results in a build time error:

> Static method 'unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)' requires that '[String : Any]' conform to 'NSCoding'

```
//create the data from dictionary
let dictionary: [String: Any] = ["Text": "Hello", "Number": 1, "Array": ["Hello", "World"]]
let data = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dictionary, requiringSecureCoding: true)

//and later get the dictionary from the data
let dictionary = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: [String: Any].self, from: data) //sorry no can do
```

Comment: Try unarchiving with `NSDictionary` and casting the final result to `[String: Any]`. `NSKeyed[Un]Archiver` should probably be avoided in Swift as should the `Any` dictionary. Use a struct and Codable in Swift for better type safety.

Comment: @HangarRash Trying to use NSDictionary throws `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'NSArray' (0x20a9295a0) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework].` In this use case the values really can be anything and the keys are unknown.

Comment: @JordanH The error message is probably right. Counter to your expectations, that archive contains an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: Yes the dictionary does contain an array for one of its values in this example @Alexander

Comment: @JordanH I'm curious, what happens if you use `NSDictionary<NSObject, NSObject>`?

Comment: Side note, if you use that "kind of data", I'd suggest to use in future `JSONSerialization`, or `Codable` & `JSONEncoder`/`JSONDecoder`, or even `PropertyList`, as I'd avoid `NSKeyedArchiver`. Maybe migrate as soon as possible with starting with the Archiving part, and leave both decoding way for legacy data. Of course, if you have in reality custom `NSObject` with `NS(Secure)Coding`, the discussion might be different.

Comment: @Larme going forward I'll use `PropertyListSerialization` thank you for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the Swift dictionary of type `[String: Any]` doesn't conform to `NSCoding`, you need to drop back to using `NSDictionary`. Since you are also using secure coding, you also need to list all types that can be in the dictionary.

You will need to use the `unarchivedObject(ofClasses:from:)` method so you can list all of the classes.

```
let dictionary = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSDictionary.self, NSArray.self], from: data) as? NSDictionary
```

You may also end up needing to add `NSString.self` and `NSNumber.self` to the list of classes. Keep adding the classes that appear in the error message until it works.

Comment: This works! I had to add NSDictionary, NSArray, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, and NSData. That's everything a plist can contain. I'm going to switch to using `PropertyListSerialization` going forward as Larme suggested and will need to use this solution for legacy data. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use this dummy object: `[NSObject.self]` instead of `[NSDictionary.self, NSArray.self ...... ]`.
With this, you cover all NS cases.
It worked for me, although purple message appears (Apple always on the safe side. Not bad, but...

> -[NSKeyedUnarchiver validateAllowedClass:forKey:]: NSSecureCoding allowed classes list contains [NSObject class], which bypasses security by allowing any Objective-C class to be implicitly decoded. Consider reducing the scope of allowed classes during decoding by listing only the classes you expect to decode, or a more specific base class than NSObject. This will become an error in the future. Allowed class list: {(
> "'NSObject' (0x219ef2d98) [/usr/lib]"
> )}

Comment: There’s a reason for the warnings. You really do not want to use just NSObject. It defeats the whole point of using secure coding.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was able to solve this issue using the following code ([Source](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737321?answerId=764405022#764405022)):

```
func loadBookmarks() {
    guard let dataFromFile = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: fullPath.path)) else { return }
    guard let bookmarksFromFile = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [
        NSDictionary.self,
        NSArray.self,
        NSString.self,
        NSURL.self,
        NSData.self
    ], from: dataFromFile) as? [URL: Data]  else {
        print("Failed to unarchive bookmarks.")
        return
    }
    let loadedBookmarks: [URL: Data] = bookmarksFromFile
}
```