# How to replace NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData with unarchivedObject when data is an array of Strings?

Tags: swift, swiftui, nskeyedunarchiver, appstorage

My project recently shows this error in Xcode:

> 'unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData' was deprecated in macOS 10.14: Use unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:) instead

I found this article which speaks to my exact problem:

[How to replace NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData with unarchivedObject when data is a Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75632048/how-to-replace-nskeyedunarchiver-unarchivetoplevelobjectwithdata-with-unarchived)

Except that my data is an array of strings, not a dictionary.  So, because I can't leave a comment on that post, I'm asking this as a new question.

How can I get the below solution to apply to [String]?

```
let dictionary = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSDictionary.self, NSArray.self], from: data) as? NSDictionary
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'd actually already tried that.  It gives me this error: `'NSArray' is not convertible to '[String]'`

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was:

```
let array = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSArray.self, NSString.self], from: data) as? [String]
```